# Convert VMs from Hyper-V to VMWare ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm having a nightmare with migrating some VMs from Hyper-V to ESXi.

The Hyper-V Server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 and the ESXi version is 6.5.

I've tried using the VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone program running on the Hyper-V Host itself with the VM I want to migrate powered off. This gives me `Insufficient permissions to connect to 'IP\ADMIN$'`.

I've also tried using the same program on the host with the server to connect to put as 'localhost'. This gives me the list of VMs in the program but when I select my powered-off VM I get:

`Permission to perform this operation was denied.`

I've also tried running the program on the VMs itself and left it overnight to export into ESXi. This failed also.

How can I get my Hyper-V VMs off this machine and into my new remote ESXi server?

Comment: The best hope is vmconverter inside the vm, what error you had ? (vmconverter got some bug that you can bypass)

Comment: `Insufficient permissions to connect to 'IP\ADMIN$` is indicated when you're not administrator on the migrating guest OS.